# Prevent Browser (Chrome) from autofilling the username login textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I would like to prevent chrome browser from auto filling the username Textbox in the account login.aspx page that I have created.

I have tried setting the Textbox's AutoCompleteMode property to "None" or to "Disabled" but still nothing.

My front end code for login:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" onloggedin="LoginUser_LoggedIn">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend><asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:chienvh.language, AccountInformation%>" /></legend>
                <p>
                    <%--<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" AutoPostBack="true" Placeholder="<%$ Resources:chienvh.language, Username%>" OnTextChanged="UserName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="failureNotification"
                                                ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                                ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <%--<asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>--%>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password" Placeholder="<%$ Resources:chienvh.language, Password%>"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLSite" DataSourceID="DSSite" DataValueField="SiteID" DataTextField="Site"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="DSSite" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                       SelectCommand="Select 'Επίλέξτε Site...' [Site], 0 SiteID
                                                      union
                                                      Select [Site], [SiteID]
                                                      from Site
                                                      order by [Site]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

And the back end:

```
   protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string error = "";
    string User_Name = LoginUser.UserName.ToString();

    if (Common.Is_Inactive_User(User_Name, ref error) || error != "")
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Roles.DeleteCookie();
        Session.Clear();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it to "off"?

Comment: try adding attribute autocomplete="off" to inputs you wanted to restrict on , it should work

Comment: There is no "off", only "Disabled" or "None". Both don't work in my asp:textbox with ID="UserName".

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I haven't been succesful so far. Autocomplete is not supported anymore. AutocompleteType=None or Disabled does nothing too. I have tried dummy textboxes with various properties and styles in order to fool the browser but nothing. Why the hell is the browser so persistent??? Developers should have the choice to let the user save or not save their credentials.